Can I conduct a repeated measures ANOVA if there is unequal spacing between measurement times?
I'm planning a longitudinal survey study with a small samples (~20-25), trying to determine the best schedule of measurements to make analysis go smoothly down the line.
My initial plan: Pre-post survey over the course of one week (pre-post educational intervention), then a follow-up measurement 1 year later and 5 years later. I was also considering a third follow up at 7 years post-intervention. FYI there is no control group.
I'd like to see if the short-term effects we see directly after intervention remain after a modest amount of time has passed - 1 year. The last two follow-up time points were selected based around the participants' stages of schooling (e.g., 5 years will be when they graduate high school) but it's not set it stone.
However I'm wondering if the unequal time between measurements / unequal spacing between levels will make analysis difficult, say if we were to conduct a repeated measures ANOVA/MANOVA. Would this likely cause problems with the sphericity assumption? Worst comes to worst, we can just do paired samples t-tests between pairs of time points, right? What would you recommend in this situation, for the schedule of measurements and analysis approach?

You could fit a mixed model with a continuous-time autoregressive model (correlation = corCAR1(form = ~time) in the nlme package in R ...)
